# microsoft identity platform authentification choice

Tags: c#, azure, oauth, azure-authentication

we are developing a web application that different customers can install on their servers. The web application uses node.js as backend, the main application is implemented in C#. The main application (C#) also has a mail client sync. For microsoft ews we are currently using Basic authentication, but now we want to replace it with Microsoft azure authentication.

I don't understand exactly which of the authentication options is best for the scenario. We want to register an Application in our Azure account (customers should not have to register an App in their Azure). Then in our web app, we want customers to be able to click a "Add Microsoft Login" button (so far, it asks for the username and password of the Microsoft account for ews). Then the user should be redirected to a Microsoft page and the required rights for ews/graph should be requested. Subsequently, the application on the customer's server should have a token that the main application (C#) can use to permanently synchronize emails in the background (preferably we would want to support application permissions and delegated permissions).

Since the application is installed at the client server, we cannot place our application secret in the application itself. For this reason, Microsoft's authentication examples like "web app" are probably not the right choice? Another idea was that the customers applications communicate with a central server of us, where the secret key of our azure application is stored. However, we don't want to have access to all customer accounts with our secret key. The tokens of the customers should remain stored on their server.

Which authentication method makes the most sense for this application?

thanks in advance!

Comment: the user interface is a web application and it communicate with a nodejs application. Other backend parts like the mail sync are in c#. The c# application backend and the nodejs can communicate. The Application is a on premises application.

Comment: Why not using Azure b2c